# gke-metrics-agents pod permission issue

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

i am receiving an error on one of my gke-metrics-agent pod deployed on GKE platform and the logs on the pod are.

Error: cannot build receivers: cannot create receiver kubenode: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied
2023/04/27 14:46:52 Failed to run the service: cannot build receivers: cannot create receiver kubenode: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied

Can anyone help in this regards,

this issue occoured suddenly not even changing any permissions on any of the service accounts and not even changing any IAM policies but still this is giving error and not able to locate which service account is being used and how this will be resolved.